# .map find elements once loaded via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following function `getItemID`, it looks for all ID's under a certain parent ID `(#search-output)`. If the ID `(#test)` was loaded when the page loads, `getItemID` finds the ID with no issue.

However I am actually building these ID's `(#test)` in realtime via AJAX, so my function `getItemID` needs to be able to find these ID's `(#test)` that have loaded via AJAX.

I think the issue here is `.map(function(){})` inside `getItemID` cannot find elements added to the DOM after the page is loaded. I need a way for this `.map` to find all elements regardless of when they were loaded.

**This works: HTML:**

```
<div id="search-output">
    <div id="test"></div>
</div>
```

**This does not work: HTML:**

```
<div id="search-output">
</div>
```

**JavaScript getItemID function:**

```
function getItemID(){
    var ID = $('#search-output [id]').map(function(){
        return this.id;
    }).get();

    if(ID.length == 0){
        return null;
    }else{
        return ID; 
    }
}
```

**JavaScript AJAX that returns the HTML:**

```
$.ajax({
    url:'lib/search-server.php',
    type:'POST',
    data: {
        search: "*"
    },
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(data){
        /* data[0] contains "<div id="test"></div>" */
        $('#search-output').append(data[0]);
    }
});
```

Comment: you need to call the function after the ajax call are you doing that... if the `getItemID` method is executed before the ajax call is completed there are no elements under `search-output` so nothing will be returned

Comment: @ArunPJohny, Oh wow this is a rookie mistake! Thanks! Should I close or do you want to put that in as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible problem here is, you are calling `getItemID` before the ajax request is completed, now `search-output` don't have any children so the method won't find any element ids to return.

So the solution is to call the `getItemID` method after the ajax call is completed and the dom is updated.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'lib/search-server.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        search: "*"
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        /* data[0] contains "<div id="test"></div>" */
        $('#search-output').append(data[0]);

        //now call the method
        var ID = getItemID();
        //do other stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing [deferred.done( doneCallbacks [, doneCallbacks ] )](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done)

> A function, **or array of functions**, that are called when the Deferred
>   is resolved.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'lib/search-server.php',
    type:'POST',
    data: {
        search: "*"
    },
    dataType:'json'
  })
  .done([function(data){
        /* data[0] contains <div id="test"></div> */
        $('#search-output').append(data[0]);
    }, getItemID]
});
```